# After converting Windows guest OS .vmdk file to .qcow2 and hosting to KVM gives "No Bootable Device"

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, qcow2

We are migrating guest VM from VMware 7 to KVM (installed on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).
We have achieved success in migrating all Ubuntu guest VM from VMware to KVM by converting the vmdk disk to qcow2.

However facing issue with Windows Guest VM with message "No bootable device" after converting from vmdk to qcow2.

[command used]
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O qcow2 WINVM.vmdk WINVM.qcow2

Tshoot done

1. Tried changing BIOS type
2. Tried changing qcow2 disk type to Sata, Scsi, VirtIO
3. Uninstalled VMware tools and installed VirtIO drivers before exporting the vmdk file and converting to to qcow2.